# Can I enter a non breaking hyphen in drupal

Tags: views

Can I enter a non breaking hyphen in drupal?
If not, how can I avoid words with hyphens to be split up when I do not want that?

Comment: A `‑` is just an HTML entity (`&#8209;`). So yes, you can enter a non breaking hyphen in Drupal.